# Conditional Relative Imports in Python ... to do or not to do?

Tags: python, import, conditional-statements, relative-path, python-packaging

Given the following package:

```
testpackage
    __init__.py
    testmod.py
    testmod2.py
```

Contents of `__init__.py`

```
from . import testmod
from . import testmod2
```

Contents of `testmod.py`

```
# relative import without conditional logic, breaks when run directly
from . import testmod2
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # do my module testing here
    # this code will never execute since the relative import 
    # always throws an error when run directly
```

Contents of `testmod2.py`

```
if __name__ == 'testpackage.testmod2':
    from . import testmod
else:
    import testmod
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test code here, will execute when the file is run directly
    # due to conditional imports
```

Is this bad? Is there a better way?

Comment: I smell future breakage in that, and a maintenance problem. I would recommend against it.

Comment: It's in the code - but to recap: relative module imports throw ValueError when you run the module directly, removing the ability to run testcode.  By adding conditional logic which checks to see if the module is being run directly or imported as part of the package, it allows me to preserve the ability to run the script directly while still using the relative import.

Answer (score 1):

That will definitely become a maintenance headache in the future. Not just the conditional imports... more the reason *why* you're having to do conditional imports, namely that running `testpackage/testmod2.py` as the main script is causing the first entry of `sys.path` to be `./testpackage` instead of `.`, which makes the very existence of testpackage *as a package* go away.

Instead, I'd recommend running testmod2 via `python -m testpackage.testmod2`, and doing it from outside `testpackage`. `testpackage.testmod2` will still show up as `__main__`, but the conditional imports will always work because `testpackage` will always be a package.

The catch with `-m` is that it requires [Python 2.5 or newer](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-m).

Comment: The only reason I'm running the modules directly is for testing/debugging.  In VIM, I bind <shift>-e to execute the current python file directly - which I use constantly to test code as I add it to the modules.  Perhaps a better solution would be to create a custom vim file which I source when loading the project that executes the module using the -m flag you referenced above.